# React Hook Form Register Different Forms With Same Field Names

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a material ui stepper in which there are multiple forms using `react-hook-form`.  When I change between steps, I would expect a new `useForm` hook to create new `register` functions that would register new form fields, but when I switch between steps, the second form has the data from the first. I've seen at least one question where someone was trying to create two forms on the same page within the same component but in this case I am trying to create two unique forms within different steps using different instances of a component.  It seems like `react-hook-form` is somehow not updating the `useForm` hook or is recycling the form fields added to the first `register` call.

Why isn't `react-hook-form` using a new `register` function to register form fields to a new `useForm` hook?  Or at least, why isn't a new `useForm` hook being created between steps?

`DynamicForm` component.  There are two of these components (one for each step in the stepper).

```js
import { Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { buttonStyles } from "../../../styles/buttonStyles";

import AppCard from "../../shared/AppCard";
import { componentsMap } from "../../shared/form";

export const DynamicForm = (props) => {
  const buttonClasses = buttonStyles();
  const { defaultValues = {} } = props;
  const { handleSubmit, register } = useForm({ defaultValues });

  const onSubmit = (userData) => {
    props.handleSubmit(userData);
  };

  return (
    <form
      id={props.formName}
      name={props.formName}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => onSubmit(data))}
    >
      <AppCard
        headline={props.headline}
        actionButton={
          props.actionButtonText && (
            <Button className={buttonClasses.outlined} type="submit">
              {props.actionButtonText}
            </Button>
          )
        }
      >
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {props.formFields.map((config) => {
            const FormComponent = componentsMap.get(config.component);
            return (
              <Grid key={`form-field-${config.config.name}`} item xs={12}>
                <FormComponent {...config.config} register={register} />
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </AppCard>
    </form>
  );
};
```

N.B. The images are the same because the forms will contain the same information, i.e. the same form fields by name.

Entry for first form:

[image]

Entry for the second form:

[image]

Each form is created with a config like this:

```js
{
  component: DynamicForm,
  label: "Stepper Label",
  config: {
    headline: "Form 1",
    actionButtonText: "Next",
    formName: 'form-name',
    defaultValues: defaultConfigObject,
    formFields: [
      {
        component: "AppTextInput",
        config: {
          label: "Field 1",
          name: "field_1",
        },
      },
      {
        component: "AppTextInput",
        config: {
          label: "Field2",
          name: "field_2",
        },
      },
      {
        component: "AppTextInput",
        config: {
          label: "Field3",
          name: "field_3",
        },
      },
      {
        component: "AppTextInput",
        config: {
          label: "Field4",
          name: "field4",
        },
      },
    ],
    handleSubmit: (formData) => console.log(formData),
  },
},
```

And the active component in the steps is handled like:

```js
import { Button, createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StepperContext } from "./StepperProvider";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    buttonsContainer: {
      margin: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    buttons: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
  })
);
export const StepPanel = (props) => {
  const { activeStep, steps, handleBack, handleNext, isFinalStep } = useContext(
    StepperContext
  );

  const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState(steps[activeStep]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveComponent(steps[activeStep]);
  }, [activeStep]);

  return (
    <div>
      <activeComponent.component {...activeComponent.config} />
      {
        isFinalStep ? (
          <div className={classes.buttonsContainer}>
            <div className={classes.buttons}>
              <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack}>
                Back
              </Button>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={props.finishFunction}
              >
                Finish And Submit
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) 
        : 
        null
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your image, every form looks the same. You should try providing a unique [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) value to your component so React know that each form is different. In this case it can be the step number for example:

```js
<activeComponent.component {...props} key='form-step-1'>
```

Comment: Perfect!  That did it.  The forms were meant to be the same (have the same names and labels) so that's why the images seemed the same.  Thanks for the help!